# $C^*$-algebra: if $0 \leq x \leq 1$, then $\|x\| \leq 1$?

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $x$ be an element of a $C^*$-algebra. If $0 \leq x \leq 1$, then $\|x\| \leq 1$?

Here, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ means that both $x$ and $1-x$ are positive elements. I think this statement should be true (and seems to be used in a proof, regarded as a trivial statement). This is true when the $C^*$-algebra is the space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space.

I want an elementary proof, not using something like that every $C^*$-algebra is isomorphic to the space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space.

Comment: This follows at once from $\sigma (1-x) = 1 - \sigma (x)$ and the fact that $\|x\| = \max \{|\lambda | : \lambda \in \sigma(x)  \}$, where $\sigma(-)$ denotes the spectrum.

Comment: @jd27 (for self-adjoint, or more generally normal, elements of a $C^\star$ algebra).  As this uses the Gelfand transform, I'm not sure the OP would count it as "elementary".

Comment: @RobertIsrael It depends on the exact definition of "positive element" OP is using. To  me (and at least to Rudin and a few other books on functional analysis) positivity means self adjoint and spectrum contained in $[0,\infty)$. In that case i dont think the Gelfand transform is used in any way. Only the spectral radius formula is needed.

Comment: @jd27 Thanks all for answers and comment. I count jd27's one-line answer as elementary. My definition is that, an element $x$ is positive if $x=y^*y$ for some element $y$. This is equivalent to what jd27 stated (maybe to prove this Gelfand transform is used, but that is fine).

Comment: Do you know that every commutative $C^*$-algebra is of the form $C_0(X)$? If you do, then it's indeed very elementary